# Amazon SES with PHP SMTP is not works

Tags: php, smtp, amazon-ses

I have used amazon ses for sending the emails. But when I add the codes which shows the error as

Email not sent. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

For anyone using the ses for php smtp, then let me know the settings changes

```
<?php

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace.
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sender = 'sender@example.com';
$senderName = 'Sender Name';

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
$recipient = 'recipient@example.com';

// Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
$usernameSmtp = 'smtp_username';

// Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
$passwordSmtp = 'smtp_password';


// If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon),
// replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP
// endpoint in the appropriate region.
$host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
$port = 25;

// The subject line of the email
$subject = 'Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using PHP)';

// The plain-text body of the email
$bodyText =  "Email Test\r\nThis email was sent through the
    Amazon SES SMTP interface using the PHPMailer class.";

// The HTML-formatted body of the email
$bodyHtml = '<h1>Email Test</h1>
    <p>This email was sent through the
    <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses">Amazon SES</a> SMTP
    interface using the <a href="https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer">
    PHPMailer</a> class.</p>';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

try {
    // Specify the SMTP settings.
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $senderName);
    $mail->Username   = $usernameSmtp;
    $mail->Password   = $passwordSmtp;
    $mail->Host       = $host;
    $mail->Port       = $port;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//    $mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', $configurationSet);

    // Specify the message recipients.
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
    // You can also add CC, BCC, and additional To recipients here.

    // Specify the content of the message.
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body       = $bodyHtml;
    $mail->AltBody    = $bodyText;
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Email sent!" , PHP_EOL;
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo "An error occurred. {$e->errorMessage()}", PHP_EOL; //Catch errors from PHPMailer.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Email not sent. {$mail->ErrorInfo}", PHP_EOL; //Catch errors from Amazon SES.
}

?>
```

Using the Amazon SES, When I run this scripts, then which shows the
Email not sent. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: Added the codes.

Comment: Can you try port `465`

Comment: Already tried with 465 port. same output

Comment: @NishadUnnikrishnan In case you haven't solved it in the meantime, how about using port `587`? I've used that one before, but with Gmail. Perhaps it would work in your case -the official documentation lists that port as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html (scroll down a bit, and choose the PHP example).

Comment: Godaddy is not allowed for sending the third party emails. That's why the error comes